# Заполнение таблицы с помощью sql запроса

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Помогите, как мне написать запрос, чтобы с помощью таблицы 1, заполнилась таблица 2. Т.е. значения столбца y в таблице 2, должны быть равны значению y в таблице 1. 7,15,26,33 чтобы именно эти значения были в таблице 2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему 5 и 7 пропущено, каковы критерии отбора ? а вообще буквально `insert into tab2(x) select x from tab1 where ...`

Comment: @mike Пропущены, потому что так и надо, что не все значения могут там быть

Comment: Но в запросе же надо указать какой то точный критерий какие именно брать...

Comment: @mike Понимаю . Получается,чтобы значения Х из  таблицы 2 , было равно  значению из таблицы 1. только в таблице 2 не все значения х , а только некоторые

Comment: В общем сначала пишите запрос select который вернет именно те значения которые нужны. А потом просто дописываете перед ним insert into

Comment: @mike попробую разобраться, спасибо

Comment: @mike Извиняюсь конечно, но как можно такое условие вообще написать? дошел до этого момента, как выше Вы и написали... Insert into Table_2 (y) (Select x From Table_1 where x

Comment: @mike Вроде сделал 

update a set
  a.y = b.y
from Table_2 a
inner join Table_1 b on a.x = b.x

Comment: Я не внимательно прочитал вопрос :( Думал надо вставлять во вторую таблицу, а не обновлять ее. Да, конечно ваше решение верное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update a set
  a.y = b.y
from Table2 a
inner join Table1 b on a.x = b.x
```